# Import error when importing files from folder

Tags: python, module

I am trying to running the [Sahana Eden](http://eden.sahanafoundation.org/wiki/InstallationGuidelines/Windows/Developer/Installer) software from terminal, but I keep getting an import error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web2py.py", line 18, in (module)
    import gluon.weidget
  File "C:\Eden\web2py\gluon\__init__.py", line 15, in (module)
ImportError: No module named 'globals'
```

[image: Sahana file system]

The globals module is right in the file where it is supposed to be. Below **init**

So I went into **init** and I removed the import to see what would happend.

```
#from globals import current
from html import *
from validators import *
```

The next local import, html, works fine, but then the next local import, "validators"(which is also right where it should be) gives me an import error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `python -V` should tell you which version of Python you're running. `--version` is also an option.